# Extra space after \@hangfrom

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I defined a command `\tstcmd` with one parameter as `\@hangfrom{[#1]{ }}\nobreak`. When using this command, I found that there is always an extra space between the right bracket and the text that follows.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\tstcmd#1{\@hangfrom{[#1]{ }}\nobreak}
%%\DeclareRobustCommand\tstcmd[1]{\@hangfrom{[#1]{ }}\nobreak}  %%No difference
\def\hf{\@hangfrom}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tstcmd{1} fsdfsd fsdfsd pppwp fsdfsd fsdfsd ewrwerw hojsoisdjf
fsdfsd fsdfsd pppwp fsdfsd fsdfsd ewrwerw hojsoisdjf fsdfsd fsdfsd
pppwp fsdfsd fsdfsd ewrwerw hojsoisdjf fsdfsd

\hf{[1]{ }}\nobreak fsdfsd fsdfsd pppwp fsdfsd fsdfsd ewrwerw
hojsoisdjf fsdfsd fsdfsd pppwp fsdfsd fsdfsd ewrwerw hojsoisdjf
fsdfsd fsdfsd pppwp fsdfsd fsdfsd ewrwerw hojsoisdjf fsdfsd

\end{document}
```

[image]

Even if `\DeclareRobustCommand` is used, the extra space remains, and apparently the `\nobreak` in `\tstcmd` is not effective. Does anyone know why it is like this and how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `\DeclareRobustCommand` has nothing to do with the problems you described. `\nobreak` should *precede* a skip (your space), not follow it. Your extraneous space comes from the fact that you write one in `{ }` and another one after `\tstcmd{1}`. I suggest something like `\newcommand*{\tstcmd}[1]{\@hangfrom{[#1]\nolinebreak\ }\ignorespaces}` given your way of using it.

Comment: In fact, `@\hangfrom` puts its argument inside a box, therefore the `\nolinebreak` is useless as written in my previous comment. It would be better before the `\ignorespaces`, I think. Thus, `\newcommand*{\tstcmd}[1]{\@hangfrom{[#1] }\nolinebreak\ignorespaces}`.

Comment: There may be exceptions (e.g., if the second space is followed by `\unskip`), but usually, yes. Two space tokens.

Comment: @frougon Now I see. Thanks a lot! Maybe you could post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Why did you delete a question? It becomes difficult to follow...

Comment: @frougon Sorry, but I've tested it right away after asking that question.

Comment: Okay, I'll add the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\DeclareRobustCommand has nothing to do with the problems you described. It would be useful if you wanted to put your `\tstcmd` calls inside the argument of a command such as `\section`, where stuff that is not \protect'ed gets *expanded* before it is written to the .toc file. \DeclareRobustCommand would make sure the command isn't expanded in such cases, but it doesn't seem very useful here.

`\nobreak` should *precede* a glue item (here, your space) when you don't want it to be a legal breakpoint, not follow it. Your extraneous space comes from the fact that you wrote one space token in `{ }` inside the macro definition and another one at the call site right after `\tstcmd{1}`. I'd suggest something like:

```
\newcommand*{\tstcmd}[1]{%
  \@hangfrom{[#1] }\nolinebreak\ignorespaces}
```

given your way of using the command (i.e., with one space token afterwards that should be ignored).